# SQL Server error converting nvarchar to bigint when using subquery through sqlalchemy in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, jupyter-notebook

I'm not able to use temp table in a subquery because of datatype conversion, although, I've performed previous steps as follows:

converted pandas DF's column:

```python
df['cust_id'] = df['cust_id'].astype('int64')
```

created MS SQL temp table declaring column type:

```python
conn.execute("""CREATE TABLE ##investors_in_defensive (cust_id bigint);""")
```

sent `df['cust_id']` to temp_table:

```python
df['cust_id'].to_sql('##investors_in_defensive', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=10000)
```

Everything seemed to work fine until this point. I actually checked for the datatype of my 'cust_id' column:

```python
conn.execute("""SELECT * FROM TempDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME IN (
SELECT NAME FROM TempDB.SYS.TABLES WHERE OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('TempDB.dbo.##investors_in_defensive')
);""").fetchall()
```

with the following output:

```text
[('tempdb', 'dbo', '##investors_in_defensive', 'cust_id', 1, None, 'YES', 'bigint', None, None, 19, 10, 0, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None)]
```

Which leads me to think that I've achieved what I wanted so far.

However, once I try to select relevant data using `##investors_in_defensive` in a subquery, I get an error.

My code:

```python
conn.execute("""SELECT * INTO ##alerts_data FROM results WHERE uniquefield IN (SELECT cust_id FROM ##investors_in_defensive)""")
```

Error message:

> ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint. (8114) (SQLExecDirectW)')
> [SQL: SELECT * INTO ##alerts_data FROM results WHERE uniquefield IN (SELECT cust_id FROM ##investors_in_defensive)]
> (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)

So, the temp table has the datatype of the column as 'bigint', but the error persists. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's the data type of the `uniquefield` column in the `results` table?

Comment: it's `nvarchar`

Comment: Well there's your issue, @punkuotukas . `cust_id` is defined as a `bigint` whoch means that to *compare* `uniquefield` to it, `uniquefield` must first be converted to a `bigint` and no all the values are valid `bigint` values. Should `cust_id` actually be a `nvarchar`? Or, perhaps, should `uniquefield` actually be a `bigint`, and the bad data removed?

Comment: Thank you @Larnu for explaining it clearly and concisely. I was able to solve my issue with converting `cust_id` to `nvarchar` and make the needed comparisons.
And thanks @AlwaysLearning for hinting towards the correct direction.